# Sktime TimeSeriesSplit with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, time-series

I try to use `cross-validation`with a timeseries for a pandas dataframe with the `sktime` `TimeSeriesSplit`. The dataframe `df` has a daily format:

```
   timepoint  balance
0  2017-03-01    1.0
1  2017-04-01    0.0
2  2017-05-01    2.0
3  2017-06-01    3.0
4  2017-07-01    0.0
...
```

I try to use `prophet` and run the following code:

```
#Packages
from sktime.forecasting.fbprophet import Prophet
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np

#preperation
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit()
rmse = []
model_ph = Prophet()

#function
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split((df)):
    cv_train, cv_test = df.iloc[train_index], df.iloc[test_index]
    ph= model_ph.fit(cv_train)
    predictions = model_ph.predict(cv_test.index.values[0], cv_test.index.values[-1])
    true_values = cv_test.values
    rmse.append(sqrt(mean_squared_error(true_values, predictions)))

#print
print("RMSE: {}".format(np.mean(rmse)))
```

which leads to the following error:

```
TypeError: X must be either None, or in an sktime compatible format, of scitype 
Series, Panel or Hierarchical, for instance a pandas.DataFrame with sktime 
compatible time indices...
```

I would have expected outputs for the `mean_squared_error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems occurs, as sktime prophet only always specific input data. In my case the solution was to create a `pd.date_range`as input for the prediction:

```
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split((df)):
    cv_train, cv_test = df.iloc[train_index], df.iloc[test_index]
    ph= model_ph.fit(cv_train)
    forecast = model_ph.predict(fh= pd.date_range(cv_test['timepoint'].values[0], periods=len(cv_test), freq='D'))
    predictions= forecast['balance'].values
    true_values = cv_test['balance'].values
    rmse.append(sqrt(mean_squared_error(true_values, predictions)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what the type of column timestamp is in your initial dataframe. Consider transformation

```
import pandas as pd
df.loc[:, "timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
```

Furthermore, if you only want the date,

```
df.loc[:, "timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"]).date
```